# How to check for warnings when using "subprocess.call"?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
exit_code = subprocess.call(command.split())
```

`exit_code` equals `1` if command terminates in an error and `0` if successfully executed. But `exit_code` also returns `0` if command terminates in a warning message.

How do I determine that the `command` returned warning message?

Comment: Best you can do is capturing `stderr` output with `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run`. The problem here is the program you're running; if the warning is serious enough that you want to handle it differently, it shouldn't be exiting with status 0 (which means "success").

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did this, 


`run(command.split())

exit_code =run(command.split() 
capture_output = True)

if exit_code.stderr:

    print('error')`
Is this the correct way? I ran the statement two times because I want to see the warning or error in terminal as well